# Jupyter notebook tqdm progress bar truncated

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cloud, google-colaboratory

I am training a DNN model and using tqdm to plot my progress. However, the progress bar is getting truncated in jupyter notebook running on AWS EC2 while I can see the full progress bar in Google Colab. How can I fix this? Below is my code to plot my batch bar.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

batch_bar = tqdm(total=len(dataloader), dynamic_ncols=True, leave=False, position=0, desc='Train')

batch_bar.set_postfix(
            loss="{:.04f}".format(running_loss/(i+1)),
            perplexity="{:.04f}".format(running_perplexity/(i+1)),
            lr="{:.04f}".format(float(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])),
            tf_rate='{:.02f}'.format(teacher_forcing_rate))
        batch_bar.update()
```

[Truncated Jupyter Notebook Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHYKN.png)

[Complete Output on Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsvLT.png)

I am expecting the output similar to the image on Google Colab